# Formdata and XMLhttpRequest not Working on IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I am using `formdata` and `XMLHttpRequest` to submit my form using ajax. Now everything works well on other browsers except IE 11 . Note I am uploading a file using this ajax request.

My code is as follows

```
var form = document.getElementById('chatMessageForm');
var formData = new FormData(form);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Add any event handlers here...
xhr.open('POST', form.getAttribute('action'), true);
xhr.responseType = "json";
xhr.send(formData);
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    var new_message_response = xhr.response; // not responseText
    console.log(new_message_response);
    if (new_message_response.conversationStatus) {
        alert('This Conversation is disabled by Other User');
        jQuery('.conversationadd .messagebox #msgbox').attr('disabled',true);
    } else {
        var downloadLink = '';
        if (new_message_response.attachment != '' && new_message_response.attachment != null) {
            downloadLink = '<a href=" ' + new_message_response.attachment_file_path + '" download="' + new_message_response.attachment + '" class="attachment">Download Attachment</a>';
        }
        jQuery('.chatmessageinner').append('<div class="singlemsg right" id=" ' + new_message_response.id + ' ">'
            + '<p> ' + msg + ' </p>'
            + '<div class="messagefooter">'
            + '<span class="time">' + new_message_response.time + '</span>'
            + downloadLink
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>');
        var objDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("chatmessageinner")["0"];
        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have edited you code with the correct indenting and removed some unnecessary text from the question. You could improve this further by indicating exactly what is not working and any error messages you may be getting in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have used jQuery.ajax instead of XMLhttpRequest now everything works smooth as silk :) Now my code looks like this:

```
var form = document.getElementById('chatMessageForm');
            var formData = new FormData(form);
jQuery.ajax({
                url: form.getAttribute('action'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var new_message_response = data;
                    if (new_message_response.conversationStatus)
                    {
                        alert('This Conversation is disabled by Other User');
                        jQuery('.conversationadd .messagebox #msgbox').attr('disabled', true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var downloadLink = '';
                        if (new_message_response.attachment != '' && new_message_response.attachment != null)
                        {
                            downloadLink = '<a href=" ' + new_message_response.attachment_file_path + '" download="' + new_message_response.attachment + '" class="attachment">Download Attachment</a>';
                        }
                        jQuery('.chatmessageinner').append('<div class="singlemsg right" id=" ' + new_message_response.id + ' ">'
                                + '<p> ' + msg + ' </p>'
                                + '<div class="messagefooter">'
                                + '<span class="time">' + new_message_response.time + '</span>'
                                + downloadLink
                                + '</div>'
                                + '</div>');
                        var objDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("chatmessageinner")["0"];
                        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
```